# How to add HTML code using JavaScript to object, where function was called?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple HTML code here:

```js
(function() {
})();

var taskGroups;
var amount = document.getElementById("results").length;

function createGroup() {
    var groupName = document.getElementById('groupName').value;
    if (groupName.length !== 0) {
        var group = { data: '<div class="card col-md-4">\n' +
            '            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="taskList">\n' +
            '                <li class="list-group-item">\n' +
            '                    <form onsubmit="createTask();">\n' +
            '                        <div class="form-group" action="#">\n' +
            '                            <label>' + groupName + '</label>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="taskName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Type task name">\n' +
            '                        </div>\n' +
            '                    </form>\n' +
            '                    <button id="createButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createTask();">Add\n</button>' +
            '                </li>' +
            '            </ul>\n' +
            '        </div>',
                    index: ''}
        document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML + group.data;
    }
    document.getElementById('groupName').value = '';

};


function createTask() {
    var taskName = document.getElementById('taskName').value;
    if (taskName.length !== 0) {
        var task = '<li class="list-group-item task">' + taskName + '</li>';
        document.querySelector("#taskList").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#taskList").innerHTML + task;
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="content">
        <div id="results"></div>
        <div class="card col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                    <form onsubmit="createGroup();return false;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Task group name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="groupName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Type group name">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <button id="createButton" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="createGroup();">Create</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it works this way: form, which you already have in HTML code creates cards, where you can add `<li>Some text from 1st form</li>`, for one current card where you used the form. Unfortunately it works only for the first card you added, others are unavalable. I know I should use `this` in some way, but I really don't know how...

I can add Groups, as many as I want. But I can add names only for the first...

And I also can't use any libraries, frameworks, etc.

Comment: Is it an option for you to use jQuery? Would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user MatrixTai is right the problem is that you have all the elements with same id, so you either need to give them different id's or you can use the [parentNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) property to select elements relative to the item clicked.
So just pass the event function parameter to click function and use that to get parentNode.

Modified JS:

```
(function() {
 })();

var taskGroups;

var amount = document.getElementById("results").length;



function createGroup() {

    var groupName = document.getElementById('groupName').value;

    if (groupName.length !== 0) {

    var group = { data: '<div class="card col-md-4">\n' +
    '            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="taskList">\n' +
    '                <li class="list-group-item">\n' +
    '                    <form onsubmit="createTask();">\n' +
    '                        <div class="form-group" action="#">\n' +
    '                            <label>' + groupName + '</label>\n' +
    '                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="taskName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Type task name">\n' +
    '                        </div>\n' +
    '                    </form>\n' +
    '                    <button id="createButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createTask(this);">Add\n</button>' +
    '                </li>' +
    '            </ul>\n' +
    '        </div>',
            index: ''}

    document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = 
    document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML + group.data;

    }

    document.getElementById('groupName').value = '';

    };


   function createTask(e) {

   var taskName = e.parentNode.querySelector('#taskName').value;
   if (taskName.length !== 0) {
       var task = '<li class="list-group-item task">' + taskName + '</li>';
       e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("#taskList").innerHTML += task;
    }
  }
```

[Working Code Link](https://jsfiddle.net/L035s7gc/13/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this line

```
var taskName = document.getElementById('taskName').value;
```

In html, `id` is unique, specific. You can't use it for second time, or it will just choose the first `<element id='taskName'>`.

So to solve your problem, you can assign a new id for each group.

Like

```
var group_count = 0;
function createGroup() {
    var groupName = document.getElementById('groupName').value;
    if (groupName.length !== 0) {
        var group = { data: '<div class="card col-md-4">\n' +
            '            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="taskList' + group_count + '">\n' +
            '                <li class="list-group-item">\n' +
            '                    <form onsubmit="createTask(' + group_count + ');">\n' +
            '                        <div class="form-group" action="#">\n' +
            '                            <label>' + groupName + '</label>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="taskName' + group_count + '" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Type task name">\n' +
            '                        </div>\n' +
            '                    </form>\n' +
            '                    <button id="createButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createTask(' + group_count + );">Add\n</button>' +
            '                </li>' +
            '            </ul>\n' +
            '        </div>',
                    index: ''}
        document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML + group.data;
    }
    document.getElementById('groupName').value = '';
    group_count++;
};
```

In createTask

```
function createTask(num) {
    var taskName = document.getElementById('taskName' + num).value;
    if (taskName.length !== 0) {
        var task = '<li class="list-group-item task">' + taskName + '</li>';
        document.querySelector("#taskList" + num).innerHTML = document.querySelector("#taskList" + num).innerHTML + task;
    }
};
```

Comment: Well...but I dun think this it is best way to do this... See if no other ans, I will update later.

Comment: Thank you fir yiur answer, I'm gonna try it!